# JBoss Monitoring with Cacti

Tags: jboss, attributes, monitoring, snmp, cacti

If there is anyone out there who has experience with monitoring JBoss with Cacti, I need help!

I used [this](http://forums.cacti.net/viewtopic.php?t=16322&highlight=jboss) template posted on the Cacti forums. It has 3 template graphs, and 2 of those graphs are working really well.

For some reason though, the third graph (Transaction Manager) isn't working. I'm get 0's for all the values. I got 0's again when I tried using snmpget command (from the Net-SNMP tool) using the oid's of the transaction attriubtes (.1.2.3.4.5.1. 6,7,8). What might be causing this?

I also need to monitor some attributes that aren't in the template. One example is Connection Count. I decided to copy the template exactly and only change the oid to get the attribute I want from JBoss. This didn't work as I get -1 for all the values in my graph. Is there anything I need to do on the JBoss side to get these attributes to graph?

Any help is appreciated as I really really need to get these graphs working soon.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the SNMP Adaptor ?

The other data graphs seems to be get directly from the SO.

https://www.webnms.com/snmpadaptor/help/jboss_snmp_adaptor/deploying_and_testing_the_jboss_snmp_agent.html